# Google maps script not workin on iphone only

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have this script inside my wp theme, its function is to on click pull google map and appended selected coordinates to the text fields.

It works perfectly fine on every platform except for iPhone and I can't figure out why.
It works perfectly fine on android devices.

If anyone has any insights on this please let me know.
[Working Example](https://sweethomeprint.com/product/date-coordinates-canvas/)

Code:

```
const html = `<div id="coordinate-modal" class="coordinate-modal">
        <div class="coordinate-modal-content">
            <span class="coordinate-modal-close">&times;</span>
            <h3 id='coordinate-modal-title'>SELECT LOCATION</h3>
            <p id='coordinate-modal-text'>You can search a specific location, either by typing in an address or by dragging the cursor on the map.
                <br />Click on <b>SET THESE COORDINATES</b> below to confirm and continue.
            </p>
            <input
                id="map-search-input"
                class="controls"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter a location"
            />
            <div id='coordinate-modal-map'></div>
            <div class="coordinate-modal-coords">
                <div class="coordinate-modal-coords-title">COORDINATES</div>
                <div id="coordinate-modal-coords-value"></div>
            </div>
            <a id='coordinate-modal-button' class="coordinate_button coordinate-modal-button">SET THESE COORDINATES</a>
        </div>
    </div>`;
    document.write(html);
    function toDegreesMinutesAndSeconds(coordinate) {
        var absolute = Math.abs(coordinate);
        var degrees = Math.floor(absolute);
        var minutesNotTruncated = (absolute - degrees) * 60;
        var minutes = Math.floor(minutesNotTruncated);
        var seconds = Math.floor((minutesNotTruncated - minutes) * 60);

        return degrees + "°" + minutes + "’" + seconds + "”";
    }

    function convertDMS(lat, lng) {
        var latitude = toDegreesMinutesAndSeconds(lat);
        var latitudeCardinal = lat >= 0 ? "N" : "S";

        var longitude = toDegreesMinutesAndSeconds(lng);
        var longitudeCardinal = lng >= 0 ? "E" : "W";

        return latitude + " " + latitudeCardinal + "&nbsp;&nbsp;" + longitude + " " + longitudeCardinal;
    }
    
    var mapLatitude = '';
    var mapLongitude = '';
    // Get the modal
    var modal = document.getElementById("coordinate-modal");

    // Get the button that opens the modal
    var btn = document.getElementById("search-coordinate-button");

    // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("coordinate-modal-close")[0];
    
    function updateLatLng(lat, lng) {
        mapLatitude = lat;
        mapLongitude = lng;
    }
    
     const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("coordinate-modal-map"), {
        center: { lat: 34.0404676, lng: -118.4681691 },
        zoom: 13,
        streetViewControl: false,
        fullscreenControl: false,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        mapTypeId: "roadmap",
      });
      // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
      const input = document.getElementById("map-search-input");
      const searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    
      map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
      // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
      map.addListener("bounds_changed", () => {
        searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
      });
      
      let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map,
        draggable: true,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        position: { lat: 34.0404676, lng: -118.4681691 },
      });
    
    
      // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
      // more details for that place.
      searchBox.addListener("places_changed", () => {
        const places = searchBox.getPlaces();
    
        if (places.length == 0) {
          return;
        }
    
        // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
        const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    
        places.forEach((place) => {
          if (!place.geometry || !place.geometry.location) {
            console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
            return;
          }
            
            const lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
            const lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
            
            marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
            updateLatLng(toDegreesMinutesAndSeconds(lat), toDegreesMinutesAndSeconds(lng));
            document.getElementById('coordinate-modal-coords-value').innerHTML = convertDMS(lat, lng);
          if (place.geometry.viewport) {
            // Only geocodes have viewport.
            bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
          } else {
            bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
          }
        });
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      });
    
    document.getElementById('coordinate-modal-coords-value').innerHTML = convertDMS(34.0404676, -118.4681691);
    
    
    
    function onMapClick(e) {
        const lat = e.latLng.lat();
        const lng = e.latLng.lng();
        
        marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));
        updateLatLng(toDegreesMinutesAndSeconds(lat), toDegreesMinutesAndSeconds(lng));
        document.getElementById('coordinate-modal-coords-value').innerHTML = convertDMS(lat, lng);
    }
    
    map.addListener("click", onMapClick);

    marker.addListener('dragend', function (event) {
        const lat = event.latLng.lat();
        const lng = event.latLng.lng();
        updateLatLng(toDegreesMinutesAndSeconds(lat), toDegreesMinutesAndSeconds(lng));
        document.getElementById('coordinate-modal-coords-value').innerHTML = convertDMS(lat, lng);
    });


    

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal //
        btn.onclick = function (ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            modal.style.visibility = "visible";
    }
    
    btn.addEventListener('touchend', function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        modal.style.visibility = "visible";
    });

    // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
    span.onclick = function (ev) {
        ev.preventDefault()
        modal.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
    
    var setCoordinateButton = document.getElementById("coordinate-modal-button");
    setCoordinateButton.onclick = function () {
        const el1 = fancyProductDesigner.currentViewInstance.getElementByTitle("COORDINATES FIRST LINE");
        const el2 = fancyProductDesigner.currentViewInstance.getElementByTitle("COORDINATES SECOND LINE");
        let append = false;
        
        if(el1.text.endsWith("”N")) {
            append = true;
        }
        
        fancyProductDesigner.currentViewInstance.setElementParameters({text: append ? `${mapLatitude}N` : mapLatitude}, el1);
        fancyProductDesigner.currentViewInstance.setElementParameters({text: append ? `${mapLongitude}W` : mapLongitude}, el2);
        
        modal.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }

    // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
    window.onclick = function (event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved.

It was # in <a href="#" call ing for it.